# Include React JS app in Ktor docker image using Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, ktor

I've got a simple Ktor application with a React frontend in `webapp/build`, which I've included in the routing configuration as

```
routing {
    singlePageApplication {
        react("webapp/build")
        defaultPage = "index.html"
    }
}
```

This works as expected when I run `./gradlew run`.  However, when I run `./gradlew runDocker`, the container starts up, but fails to serve the React frontend.

How can I configure the Ktor Gradle plugin, to include the content in `webapp/build` and use the path specified in the `singlePageApplication` config?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my question.

In the react app I've added the following line to copy the build to `resources/html`

```
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "postbuild": "mv build ../src/main/resources/html"
   }
```

And the routing looks like this now

```
singlePageApplication {
    react("/html/")
    defaultPage = "index.html"
    useResources = true
}
```

By adding the `useResource` flag, the webapp is found in the Docker container as well as running it on my dev machine locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by configuring `jib` to copy the `webapp` directory when building the image. Add the following configuration in the `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
jib {
    extraDirectories {
        paths {
            path {
                setFrom("webapp")
                into = "${jib.container.appRoot}/webapp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the container, but unfortunately breaks when running on my dev machine `./gradlew run`.

Comment: How exactly does it beak? The above configuration shouldn't affect the `Application` Gradle plugin.